# Guice error when trying to use Alf Xtext parser as Standalone

Tags: eclipse, guice, xtext, papyrus

I am trying to write a plugin for Papyrus that converts Alf code.

I tried to use the Alf-parser that is already included in Papyrus (org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.*). So I tried to instantiate the parser as written [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/FAQ#How_do_I_load_my_model_in_a_standalone_Java_application.C2.A0.3F):

```
public class Activator extends Plugin {

    // default Activator code here ...

    public String ConvertAlfToSpecSharp(String alf)
    {
        new org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup().setPlatformUri("../");
        Injector injector = new AlfStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);
        resourceSet.addLoadOption(XtextResource.OPTION_RESOLVE_ALL, Boolean.TRUE);
        // ...
    }
}
```

But the first line (`new org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup().setPlatformUri("../");`) throws the following exception:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Error injecting method, java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EPackages were registered for the validator org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.validation.CommonJavaValidator please override and implement getEPackages().
at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.AbstractInjectableValidator.register(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.xtext.service.MethodBasedModule.configure(MethodBasedModule.java:55)
while locating org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.validation.CommonJavaValidator

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:183)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjector(CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:22)
at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.CommonStandaloneSetup.doSetup(CommonStandaloneSetup.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.AlfStandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(AlfStandaloneSetupGenerated.java:20)
    at <packagenamehere>.Activator.ConvertAlfToSpecSharp(Activator.java:113)
```

I have no idea how to solve this, especially since I find it very hard to debug eclipse applications...

Update:
Here are links to some relevant classes (all from the org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common plugin of Papyrus plugins ([link](http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/plain/plugins/uml/alf/))):

- [org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.CommonStandaloneSetup](http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/plain/plugins/uml/alf/org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common/src/org/eclipse/papyrus/uml/alf/CommonStandaloneSetup.java)
- [org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated](http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/plain/plugins/uml/alf/org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common/src-gen/org/eclipse/papyrus/uml/alf/CommonStandaloneSetupGenerated.java)
- [org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.validation.CommonJavaValidator](http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/plain/plugins/uml/alf/org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common/src/org/eclipse/papyrus/uml/alf/validation/CommonJavaValidator.java)
- [org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.validation.AbstractCommonJavaValidator](http://git.eclipse.org/c/papyrus/org.eclipse.papyrus.git/plain/plugins/uml/alf/org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common/src-gen/org/eclipse/papyrus/uml/alf/validation/AbstractCommonJavaValidator.java)

Comment: Can you provide the content of CommonStandaloneSetup.java please?

Comment: Also can you provide the content of CommonJavaValidator.java and AbstractCommonJavaValidator.java (his direct parent) please? As suggested in the error message, the method getEPackages() returns an empty list.

Comment: The classes are all from the alf.common plugins of Papyrus. I have added the links above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the method `getEPackages()` of AbstractCommonJavaValidator.java returns an empty list.

If you look at this [AbstractAlfJavaValidator](https://github.com/ApexSoft/modellipse/blob/master/org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf/src/org/eclipse/papyrus/uml/alf/validation/AbstractAlfJavaValidator.java) implementation, there is an EPackage which is added to the list.

As a solution, i think you should edit CommonJavaValidator.java and override getEPackages() in order to add an EPackage:

```
@Override
protected List<EPackage> getEPackages() {
    List<EPackage> result = super.getEPackages();
    // result.add(org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.alf.AlfPackage.eINSTANCE);
    // Edit
    result.add(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage.eINSTANCE);
    return result;
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you can't edit papyrus plugins, it think you should add the following before your code:

`if (!EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.containsKey("http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/alf/Alf")) {
    EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.put("http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/alf/Alf", org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.alf.AlfPackage.eINSTANCE);
}`

It will add an EPackage before the guice creation and the exception will avoided.

Comment: If I edit CommonJavaValidator as in your first solution, then I get a cyclic dependency error because AlfPackage is in plugin org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf which relies on org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.alf.common where the CommonJavaValidator is. Your second solution does not do anything for me. I inserted the code right before `new org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup().setPlatformUri("../");`

Comment: Ok, then can you try this one instead? `result.add(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage.eINSTANCE);`

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you very much. You should update your answer to this solution.